# Error:An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
 {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=2500, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 2500;
            "fbtrace_id" = DiBO16GER0C;
            message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=An active access token must be used to query information about the current user., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0}
```

I am facing the above error. I know this was already discussed but they fixed using `FBSession` . In the Latest SDK i did not see the FBSession. Please help me i am stuck on this for whole day.

**Issue coming under:**
  I have 3 pages (Login page, username page, find friends page). In login page i just authenticate with facebook and get the user information from the graphAPI it works fine. Then come to the page username here normal registration process from user. Then i come to the find friends page here i facing the issue that is, If i come with the flow(login -> username -> find friends page) i can list the facebook friends using graphAPI **BUT** i could not get the friends list when i kill the app and open this page directly it shows above error. I dont know how to get back from this. Please help anybody felt this before.

**My code are below,**
  *Find Friends Page:*

```
 if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) 
{
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:url parameters:@{ @"fields": @"id,picture"}]
                 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
                 {
                       NSLog(@"result === %@",result);
                       if (!error)
                       {}
                       else
                       {}
    }];
  }
else
{
  NSLog(@"There is no current access token");
}
```

*Note:
    The current access token is null when i kill the app and come back to the username page again.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

This will be surely helpful to someone, Actually i did mistake in this place,  `[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:url parameters:@{ @"fields": @"id,picture"}]`  This method not have the access token ever. But wonder is the access token is not enable in the whole app. it will be null when i move to the next page after kill the app. So i just save the token string in NSUserDefaults like

```
NSString *access_token=[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString;
[NSUSER setObject:access_token forKey:@"fb_token"];
 [NSUSER synchronize];
```

And then wherever i call the graphAPI i use this method with tokenstring like,

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:url parameters:@{ @"fields": @"id,picture"} tokenString:[NSUSER objectForKey:@"fb_token"] version:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"]
             startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
             {
}];
```

Simple but it takes too long to find. Glad!

Answer (score 1):

This will help you in swift 2.0

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
                 openURL url: NSURL,
                         sourceApplication: String?,
                         annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
        application,
        openURL: url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working fine for me Swift 3
Put this code where friend list or fb user data received:have look

```
let token = FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString  
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(token, forKey: "fb_token")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()


let params = ["fields": "id, first_name, last_name, name, picture"]


let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/friends", parameters: params, tokenString: UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "fb_token") as! String, version: nil, httpMethod: "GET")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a Facebook's bug, You need call graph api in this way:

```
    NSString *graphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/videos?access_token=%@", @"me", [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString];
    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:graphPath parameters:dict tokenString:alreadyAuthToken version:@"v2.12" HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Just put the access_token in request url, and other params put in param 'parameters:'